# Why is the first item in the Spinner not working

Tags: android, android-spinner, onselect

I wanted the spinner to select from the following 3 countries but im only able to access the 2nd and 3rd option. When i select the first option the spinner doesn't work.

```
 String[] countries = { "INDIA","AUSTRALIA","ENGLAND"};


 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {

            if (!mSpinnerInitialized) {
                mSpinnerInitialized = true;
                return;
            }
            if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("INDIA")){
                LocaleManager.setNewLocale(LoginActivity.this, "en");
                restart();

            }else if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("AUSTRALIA")){
                LocaleManager.setNewLocale(LoginActivity.this, "si");
                restart();

            }else if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("ENGLAND")){
                LocaleManager.setNewLocale(LoginActivity.this, "ta");
                restart();
            }
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Spinner Initialization

```
ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.languagespinner,countries);
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(aa);
```

The spinner text named INDIA should be accessed but I cannot do it unfortunately.

EDIT

It might be because of the mSpinnerInitialized but if i remove that , the activity is restarted in an endless loop

Comment: Check, if  (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString.equals("INDIA") is true, by using System.out or a toast or log. Maybe you have missed something. Could you show us the xml of the spinner and how you fill it with values?

Comment: Use the android debugger and put a stop on the first if and check your value

Comment: It doesn't go into the onselected method whenever I press the first item of the spinner

Comment: The second and third if conditions work though

Comment: Could you show us the Spinner inilitiziation?

Comment: Added the initialization

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
private String[] arraySpinner;
```

in `onCreate` do this:

```
this.arraySpinner = new String[]{"INDIA", "AUSTRALIA", "ENGLAND"};

Spinner yourSpinner = findViewById(R.id.yourSpinnerID);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
yourSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        if(selectedItem.equals("INDIA")){
            // DO YOUR LOGIC
        }
    }
}
```

To change your language use this code:

```
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static void onCreate(Context context) {

        String lang;
        if(getLanguage(context).isEmpty()){
            lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        }else {
            lang = getLanguage(context);
        }

        setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static void onCreate(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static void setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);
        updateResources(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private static void updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());


    }
}
```

And in your Spinner Class use this method to change the language:

```
LocaleHelper.setLocale(this,"en") //for english;
LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, "de") // for german
```

And for restart use this method:

```
public static void restartActivity(Activity activity){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        activity.recreate();
    } else {
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(activity.getIntent());
    }
}
```

Comment: Same result. Clicking on AUSTRALIA and ENGLAND works but clicking on INDIA doesnt even go into the onItemSelected method

Comment: I tested and it works for me. Clean and rebuild your project again.

Comment: The problem is the restart method. It does work. However since the default value during creation of the activity is INDIA, the activity keeps getting restarted endlessly

Comment: Delete everything and try my code, it will work. Don't use restart for now, just test my code.

Comment: Yes it does work lol. But i need the activity to restart. Thats why im finding it diffcult to figure out a solution

Comment: Why do you want to restart the activity? What is your intention.

Comment: I need the language to change. It doesn't change unless i close and open the app again

Comment: You can change your language using `Locale`, you don't need to restart your app for that.

Comment: It doesn't change when i click on it. :(. i have to refresh the app for that

Comment: I again edited my answer, now you can restart your Activity without having troubles with the `Spinner`